# find torsion coefficients of groups

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

I have to find torsion coefficients of groups $G_1\simeq Z/2\oplus Z/4\oplus Z/3\oplus Z/3\oplus Z/9$ and $G_2\simeq Z/15\oplus Z/20\oplus Z/18$. I want to ask if my calculations are correct.

For $G_1$: Since $(4,9)=(2,3)=1$, we have that $G_1\simeq Z/3\oplus Z/6\oplus Z/36$, and from The fundamental theorem of finitely generated abelian groups we have that torsion coefficients of $G_1$ are $3,6$ and $36$.

For $G_2$: Analogously as for $G_1$ we have that torsion coefficients of $G_2$ are $30$ and $180$.

Answer (score 1):

Your calculations are correct.

$G_1$ is already expressed in primary decomposition and so to find the invariant factors you just list the powers of each prime in increasing order right justified and multiply them vertically:
\begin{array}{rrr}
  & 2 & 4 \\
3 & 3 & 9 \\
\hline
3 & 6 & 36 \\
\end{array}
This gives $G_1 \cong  C_3 \times C_6 \times C_{36}$.

The primary decomposition of $G_2$ is $C_3 \times C_5 \times C_4 \times C_5 \times C_2 \times C_9$ and so the invariant factors are:
\begin{array}{rr}
2 & 4 \\
3 & 9 \\
5 & 5 \\
\hline
30 & 180 \\
\end{array}
This gives $G_2 \cong  C_{30} \times C_{180}$.